# Null Exception when running exe via batch file in C#, but not when clicking the batch manually

Tags: c#, batch-file

We have a 3rd party exe that was built for us. It reads word docs and turns them into XML so we can process them.

We have a batch file that runs fine when clicked. It just loops over all the docs in our doc folder and passes the parameters to the WordExtract.exe:

```
for %%a in (MyPATH\*.doc) do WordExtract.exe -InputFile="%%a" -TempFile0="%%a.html" -OutputFile= "%%a.xml"
```

When we try to call it in our C# code however, it gives us a null reference exception for the WordExtract.exe

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=WordExtract
  StackTrace:
       at WordExtract.Converter.word2text(FileInfo file, FileInfo txtfile)
       at WordExtract.Program.Main(String[] args)
  InnerException:
```

So it's calling the batchfile fine. I'm just not sure why the batchfile produces no errors when I run it manually, but somehow has a null exception when run Programatically.

I also had the same result when trying to just run the exe in command prompt manually and programatically. Works fine when done manually and gives the above error when run programatically.

Any ideas on this? Running the batch file should produce the same results either way. It doesn't take any inputs at all so I can't be screwing that up programatically.

Here's the code for running my batch file:

```
Process proc = new Process();
            string targetDir = string.Format(@"C:\BatchTest");//this is where batch.bat is
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = targetDir;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "batch.bat";
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Does the batch file take any command-line arguments?

Comment: I'll take the Sgt Schultz about `c#`, but what's the `@` doing in the `string.format` statement?

Comment: @PeterWright, the `@` means the string can contain \ without having to escape it.

Comment: @Ryan Frame, no arguments. The batch file literally just needs to be run (when clicked manually)>

Answer (score 1):

The file that you need to Execute is "CMD.exe" and the batch file you want to run is your argument :-

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", "/c C:\\BatchTest\\batch.bat");
```

Comment: I've gone down that route as well with the same null exception.

Comment: Well that is quite bizarre, would you normally run this batch file from the root of you c: drive on Your machine or is this running on a Server? I'd ask for support from the 3rd party company, as its there program that is throwing the exception.

Comment: Yeah I thought it was really weird too... Ultimately it would be running from our webserver. Right now, I'm just trying to get it working on my local machine though. I did email the third party to see if they had any ideas. It's just really weird that the batch file runs fine when clicked, and doesn't when run in C#.

Comment: The only thing i can think of mate, is that when your running that on your C drive, when it looks into the folder for *.doc objects its not finding any and therefore throwing a null exception?? you could try using c# altogether instead of using teh batch file mind. Use the WordExtract,Exe as your process, and pass the arguments in too that goes with it. You can ope a process for each file in the folder? try that?

Comment: Tried that one too. I just posted about the batch file here because I thought it would be the simplest to understand and rule out programming errors on my end. Ie the batch file takes no parameters where as running the exe directly involves passing parameters.